# Squarespace ajax call do not load video and audio

Tags: ajax, audio, video, squarespace

i'm working with squarespace developer mode, i create some javascript code to get my blog articles or events, the problem i have is that when i use ajax call to get my events to display them in a page i've created, the data is loaded correctly except blocks having audios and videos, i had the same issue with images, but SQS gives a solution for images :

`var images = document.querySelectorAll('img[data-src]' );
        for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
        ImageLoader.load(images[i], {load: true});
      }`

But this do not solve the audio and videos blocks, i've tested every single code part existing on SQS forums but none of them work, ive also tested what suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39409881/how-can-i-bind-events-to-the-squarespace-ajaxloader#) but no solution.

Here is my code to get events:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var url = '/test-blog?format=json';
$.getJSON(url).done(function(data) {
  var items = data.items;

  var $_container = $('#events-container-concert');
  var result = "";
  var appendText = [];
  items.forEach(function(elm) {
    var body = elm.body;
    var $_body = $(body);

    appendText.push("<div class='blog-item'><div id='body'>"+body+"</div>");
  });   

  appendText.join(" ");
  $_container.html(appendText);

  var images = document.querySelectorAll('img[data-src]' );
    for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    ImageLoader.load(images[i], {load: true});
  }
 });
});
```

Please is there anyone who had this issue on SQS?
no one answered my question on SQS forums
Thanks

Comment: I think this is solvable. Is it possible for you to provide a link to the page in question with the code working?

Comment: hi @Brandon here is the [link](https://davids-developer.squarespace.com/events/), the code is updated look above, i appreciate your answer, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may use this to automatically load all the blocks (I believe even the image blocks, but if not then pair it with your call to ImageLoader):

```
window.Squarespace.AFTER_BODY_LOADED = false;
window.Squarespace.afterBodyLoad();
```

Of course, you'll want to wait until the content is on the page. You can pull up the page you linked-to and then run those two lines via console as a quick test. Worked well for me in that context.

Reference: https://github.com/Squarespace/squarespace-core/blob/master/src/Lifecycle.js

Comment: Thanks a lot Brandon, i've been looking for this solution months ago on SQS forums none of the folks mention this solution. I appreciate your dedication